# Loop within IF statement condition

Tags: c++, qt4, if-statement

i just want to know if there is a way for a loop to be on the If statement condition?

sample:

```
if((string.contains(stringlist.hello().value(0),Qt::CaseInsensitive))||(string.contains(stringlist.hello().value(1),Qt::CaseInsensitive))||(string.contains(stringlist.hello().value(2),Qt::CaseInsensitive)))
{
...
}
```

to be:

```
if
(
for(int i=0; i < stringlist.hello().size(); i++)
{
string.contains(stringlist.hello().value(i),Qt::CaseInsensitive)
}
)
{
...
}
```

by the way hello() function retrieves list of data from the database.
the purpose of this program is to check a string if it contains some keywords from the database.

Comment: Even if this were valid syntax, it would be a bad idea because it is hard to read.  This is what functions are for...  Create a function to perform the loop, give it a meaningful name, then just call it as the predicate of the `if`.

Comment: Throwing in a space every once in a while would make it easier to read too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That code will not compile; instead, you might try a solution that checks each condition and stores the result into a variable determining whether or not the condition is met:

```
bool testCond = false;
for(int i=0; i < stringlist.hello().size(); i++)
{
    if (string.contains(stringlist.hello().value(i),Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
        testCond = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (testCond)
{
    // code here if any of the conditions in the for loop are true
}
```

I changed my code to use bool instead of int's, as it looks like you are using C++.

Comment: you might as well put a `break` in that first `if`, so that you don't waste time after `testCond = true;`

Or, you could change the `for` condition to `!testCond && i < stringlist.hello().size()`.